# Can we create a custom visualforce page accessing a controller that is a Managed Package object?

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package

I am trying to create a button that is invoking a VF page which accesses a controller that is a Managed Package object. 
[image]

The code in VF page is a basic code to display title.

```
    <apex:page standardController="CameleonCPQ__Quote__c" 
    lightningstylesheets="true" extensions="ContractClone">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Close Quote"/>
    </apex:page>
```

However, when I click on the button - it gives me an error.
What could be the possible reason for this? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Issues is not in the VF page but it is in the button itself. Can you share what is the code behind the button? What is a URL generated by that?

Comment: @kurunve I have updated the details, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether the controller contains Global methods for access in your Salesforce org. Also, you will need to provide namespace of the Managed package when you are referring the class in the extensions attribute